# Comments on flags - would be good if you needed to be less proactive to be aware of them

Tags: feature-request, flag-history

I idly clicked on my "x helpful flags cast" link in my profile, and came across this message on one of my flags:

> declined - I'm assuming you flagged this as "very low quality" because of the severe spelling/grammar problems. However, those are things that can and should be fixed by editing, not a moderator.

This message reads as a manually entered comment by whichever moderator saw my flag. *However*, if I had been less proactive I would not have been aware of this message at all, when this message is obviously intended to be educational for me.

My proposed feature request is that I get a notification of some kind when a moderator responds to one of my flags in such a way, with quick access to the message itself.

Comment: Also, on MSE: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/show-declined-flags-in-inbox) [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239738/send-custom-flag-responses-to-messages-inbox)

Comment: My bad, I searched but apparently not well enough

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, when your most recent flag is declined, you are shown a notification of that the next time you try and raise a flag. (Yes, that was a manually-entered message.)